# Connection Refused when using postgresql in a django-jython project

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, jython

According to the [jythonbook](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonDjango.html), the program works well before I sync the database, however, When I use `jython manage.py syncdb`, I am getting this error:

```
connection = zxJDBC.connect(self.get_jdbc_connection_url(),
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. [SQLCode: 0], [SQLState: 08001]
```

My env is

```
ubuntu 13.10
java version "1.7.0_25"
Jython 2.7b3
Django 1.7.1
django_jython-1.7.0b2
```

and my setting.py like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'polls',
)

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'doj.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'vanxin.db'),
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
    'USER': 'vanxin',
    'PASSWORD': 'vanxin',
}
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: The reason is that I did not start postgresql server...

Comment: had the same thing, thanks for sharing the comment